# Edit This Bookmark box not appearing in Firefox 14

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

Yesterday I upgraded my firefox to firefox version 14.1. After using it for sometime I realized that when I press Ctrl + D or click the star icon, the bookmark is saved but I am not getting the 'Edit This Bookmark' box.

I was using Xmarks. So I tried bookmarking after disabling Xmarks, but Edit This Bookmark box still doesn't appear.

Comment: You sure it was that way? I can only remember it being "Click once for bookmark, click twice/a second time for edit".

Comment: Ctrl+D should bring up the "Page Bookmarked" or "Edit this Bookmark" popup. However, when you click the star if it is not bookmarked, you get no popup. If it is bookmarked, you get the "Edit this Bookmark" popup. This is the normal behavior, as also confirmed by Bobby.

Comment: @iglvzx sites are bookmarked but still i don't get any popup.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got the problem. It was due to an addon named Compact Menu 2 v.4.3.1
I tried by using firefox in safe mode with addons disabled. And then checked by disabling and enabling individual addons.